# Inequality real analysis about logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality, proof-writing, logarithms

Can you proof that

> $$\forall t \ge -1, (1+t)\log(1+t) -t \ge \frac{t^{2}}{2(1+\frac{t}{3})} $$

A elegant proof will be appreciated !

I tried derivation and power series.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Derivation and power series. I think power serie works but I got lost.

Comment: @CechMS Why you deleted your words about your attempts? Without these words this topic will be deleted. Restore please your words and it will be better, write your attempts

Comment: Delete it if you want.

Comment: Your topic will be deleted not by me. But will be deleted my solution. Do you think it will be fair?

Comment: Okay I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t)=(1+t)\ln(1+t)-t-\frac{t^2}{2\left(1+\frac{t}{3}\right)}.$

Thus, $$f''(t)=\frac{t^2(t+9)}{(t+1)(t+3)^3}\geq0.$$
Thus $f'$ increases.

But $$f'(t)=\ln(1+t)-\frac{3t(t+6)}{2(t+3)^2}\rightarrow-\infty$$ for $t\rightarrow-1^+$ and $f'\rightarrow+\infty$ for $t\rightarrow+\infty$, which says that $0$ is an unique root of $f'$,

which gives that for $t=0$ our function gets a minimal value.

Id est,  $$f(t)\geq f(0)=0$$ and we are done!

Comment: Why the root is unique ?

Comment: @CechMS Because $f'$ increases and $f'(0)=0.$

Comment: But not strictly increasing so it could locally be $0$.

Comment: @CechMS It does not change something. The root must be unique. Use the definition of the increasing function. $f'(a)<f'(0)<f'(b)$ for $a<0<b.$

Comment: The definition is $f'(a)\le f'(0)\le f'(b)$ .

Comment: @CechMS $f''(t)=0$ for $t=0$ only. Thus, $f'(t)>0$ for $t>0$ and $f'(t)<0$ for $-1<t<0$.